# Only the last menu is working

Tags: javascript, html

The value of u and v are coming correctly as 1 and 0... but the values are not being used in the statement "t[i].children[v].onclick=function(){}" ..!! This works perfectly when I used 1 in the place of u and 0 in the place of v!!! Here is the code :

```
    <div class="dropdown">
    <span class="menu-toggler">Menu</span>
    <ul>
    <li>First Part</li>
    <li>Second Part</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
    <span class="menu-toggler">Menu</span>
    <ul>
    <li>First Part</li>
    <li>Second Part</li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

   function init()
   {
    t = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown");
    for(var i=0;i<t.length;i++)
    {
        v = parseInt(getMenuToggler(t[i]));
        u = parseInt(getDropDown(t[i]));

    (function (v, u){

    t[i].children[v].onclick = function() {
    if (this.parentNode.children[u].classList.contains("menu-open")) {
        this.parentNode.children[u].classList.remove("menu-open");
      } else {
        this.parentNode.children[u].classList.add("menu-open");
      }
    };

   })(getMenuToggler(t[i]), getDropDown(t[i]));
    }
    }

    function getDropDown(x)//this function is perfectly ok
    {
    for(j=0;j<x.childElementCount;j++)
    {
        if(x.children[j].classList.contains("dropdown-menu"))
        return j;
    }
    return -1;
    }

   function getMenuToggler(y) // this function is perfectly ok
   {
    for(k=0;k<y.childElementCount;k++)
    {
        if(y.children[k].classList.contains("menu-toggler"))
        return k;
    }
    return -1;
    }
     </script>
    <script>window.onload=init;</script>
```

thank you in advance... :)

Comment: since switching numbers works have you tried `v = parseInt(getMenuToggler(t[i]));`

Comment: I did and its working... thank you @Craicerjack .. but now if I add more dropdown elements its not working out!!! only the last dropdown is getting a "menu-open" class!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using the variables in an event handler bound in a loop, you need one set of variables for each iteration in the loop. Otherwise all event handlers will use the same variables, and get the values for the last item in the loop.

Use a function wrapper to create a set of varibles for each iteration:

```
for (var i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {

  (function (v, u){

    t[i].children[v].onclick = function() {
      if (this.parentNode.children[u].classList.contains("menu-open")) {
        this.parentNode.children[u].classList.remove("menu-open");
      } else {
        this.parentNode.children[u].classList.add("menu-open");
      }
    };

  })(getMenuToggler(t[i]), getDropDown(t[i]));

}
```

Comment: tried it as well.. thank you :) @Guffa but the problem remains the same!!! it is not working at all with 1 "dropdown" list.... but if I use 2 "dropdown" lists only the last "dropdown" is working... and if I add 3 "dropdowns" the page is not loading!!!!

Comment: @SamarpanDas: That's because you are using global variables everywhere. The loops in `getMenuToggler` and `getDropDown` overwrites the value in `i`, so `t[i]` doesn't work. Declare the variable `i` locally in the functions: `for (var i = ....`. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/mmax3v7c/

Comment: @SamarpanDas: It also works when `u` and `v` are different between the items (which is the whole point of getting the indexes dynamically): http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/mmax3v7c/2/

Comment: Thank You @Guffa... :) but check out my edited post... it works but when I have more than 1 "dropdown" menu only the very last menu works!!! I have used your code and declared the variables i, j and k locally.... :) so why is that happening and how can I solve it?

Comment: @SamarpanDas: Please don't change the original code in the question, then it looks like all answers are suggesting things that you already have in the code... Add a new version of the code instead. Naming the variables differently doesn't make them local, but it should circumvent the immediate problem that you have (you will only run into other problems later because of conflicting global variables). Look at the examples that I linked to in the commends, where it works fine with three menus.

Comment: Thank You @Guffa :) it runs flawlessly... and I am sorry for changing the question... just one last favour... if u could give me a link where i cud get a clear idea about the console.log() .... I would be really obliged to u... :)

Comment: @SamarpanDas: Here is the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log and searching for [browser console](https://www.google.se/search?q=browser+console) gives you descriptions for different browsers and other tips.